# Event.listens_for not updating Engine inside of Session

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have this issue, where my created event does not update the Engine's password inside of my Session.

I have this file `db.py` which has the code:

```py
__Engine = __connect_to_mysql_db() # this returns a create_engine()
Session = sessionmaker(bind=__Engine)

@event.listens_for(__Engine, 'do_connect')
def provide_token(dialect, conn_rec, cargs, cparams):
    cparams['password'] = get_authentication_token()

# To check whether the password has been updated inside the session
@event.listens_for(Session, 'do_orm_execute')
def receive_do_orm_execute(orm_execute_state):
    print(orm_execute_state.session.bind.url.password)
```

This is done, because I want to connect to AWS RDS instance, but with each query to have a new password.

The `Session` is imported into the `db_queries.py` file and executed as so:

```py
def get_information(item_id: int):
    with Session() as session:
        result = session.query(
            Item
        ).filter(
            Item.id == item_id
        ).first()

    return result
```

How can I update the password of the Engine inside the Session, so that every time my query is executed it has a new password?

Comment: I think you'd need to listen for connection events, assuming you are only authenticating each time you make a new connection (sessions use existing connections, so they don;t authenticate).  By default SQLAlchemy maintains a connection pool, so you'd need to check how often pool connections get recycled.

Comment: @snakecharmerb I was not defining the `pool_recycle` inside the `create_engine`, so after setting it set's say to 5 seconds, it didn't have any impact on the connection credentials. Based on the `receive_do_orm_execute` event, the same password is being used to access the DB.